# Note to self: DO NOT FORGET!

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, seasonal, connect-wall

Just found this connecting wall on a scrap of paper in my pocket. I know I created it as a reminder about something... I just can't for the life of me remember what!

Can you help me recall what the four correctly matched groups of four were supposed to prompt me about?

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BOARD | BOOST | FOUR | GAME |
| IFF | LION | OCCURS | PENGUIN |
| ROMAN | SHARP | SIXTEEN | SORE |
| SWAMP | TASER | TAXI | UPLIT |

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a reminder of

> What to get for Valentine's Day!

As the categories are:

> **Flowers**, a **Card**, **Chocolate** and **Candles**!

---

The groups:

> **Anagrams of flowers:**
>
> UPLIT -> TULIP
> SORE -> ROSE
> OCCURS -> [CROCUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocus)
> TASER -> [ASTER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aster_(genus))
>
> **Card____:**
>
> CARD-BOARD
> CARD-GAME
>  [CARD-IFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiff)
>  [CARD-SHARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_sharp)
>
> **Types of Chocolate Bar**
>
> LION
> BOOST
> PENGUIN
> TAXI
>
> **____Candles**
>
>  [FOUR-CANDLES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Candles)
>  [SIXTEEN-CANDLES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixteen_Candles)
> ROMAN-CANDLES
>  [SWAMP-CANDLES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysimachia_terrestris)

Comment: Ah dang you both are too quick just figured out the answer !! I think only us Brits would find this quickly.

Comment: @PDT With the third category here, the one-word British ones seem to lend themselves more nicely to a connecting wall than the US ones, which often have much more giveaway names!

Comment: @Stiv added some wiki links, just did anything I had to google myself but feel free to edit in any other links you think would be appropriate!

Comment: I think that this should have the check mark as most useful to future readers (and it saves me from fiddling with cut and paste on my phone)

Comment: @DanielS honestly don’t mind either way, both good answers :)

Comment: Both answers good, but awarding the checkmark here for the extra added detail. Thanks both for helping me work out what I need to do tonight - 6pm here now, time's running out!

Comment: @Stiv Also card-iff that is a tricky spot if you aren’t a Brit

Answer (score 12):

It’s not too late to

> get ready for Valentine’s Day!

Categories

> Anagrams of flowers OCCURS SORE TASER UPLIT

> Brands of chocolate BOOST LION PENGUIN TAXI

> Prefixes for card BOARD GAME IFF SHARP

> Words to precede candles FOUR SIXTEEN ROMAN SWAMP

Comment: Think you sniped me to the final answer, I finished mine off whilst your original post only had two categories, but think you still got all 4 just before I posted, gg :)

Comment: Nicely done. I was typing on a phone on the train and fat thumbed the “post” button. Have an upvote for having better typing skills.

Comment: Ha! Not really a fair comparison then if I'm on laptop :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil and DanielS: Well done both - these are indeed the intended categories... If anyone feels like adding some Wikipedia links to some of the more difficult-to-grasp connections (e.g. IFF, SWAMP, FOUR and SIXTEEN) that would make for a nicely rounded out answer... Thanks :)

Comment: Hmmm.  I guess this is a UK puzzle.  I've never heard of any of those chocolate bars, nor Four-Candles, nor connecting walls for that matter!